# Binding parameters in qiskit

Tags: qiskit

when I want to bind parameters in circuit below, it gives error:
 `CircuitError: 'Cannot bind parameters (theta, phi, landa, gama) not present in the circuit.'`

```
theta_val=[rand_list]
phi_val=[rand_list]   
landa_val=[rand_list]
gama_val=[rand_list]  

gate = 0
for i in range(layer):
    for j, (control, target) in enumerate(cnot_pairs):
        # bind the initial parameter values
        bound_circuit =[circuit.bind_parameters(
    {theta: theta_val, phi: phi_val, landa: landa_val, gama: gama_val}) 
     for (theta_val, phi_val, landa_val, gama_val) in zip(theta_val, phi_val, landa_val, gama_val)]
        bound_circuit.cu(theta, phi, landa, gama, qreg_q[control], qreg_q[target])
        gate += 1

circuit.draw(output='mpl')
```

i want to bind these parameters and use to optimize the circuit.

Comment: I don't know qiskit, but looking at the documentation...did you create the parameters before trying to bind them? Look at the example here: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.Parameter.html

Comment: yes, I used 

`from qiskit.circuit import Parameter
theta = Parameter('theta')
phi = Parameter('phi')
landa = Parameter('landa')
gama = Parameter('gama')`